# WordPress calls archive page instead of Custom Page Template

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I have created a custom post type called "Projects".

My permalinks settings is postname and I'd like to keep it that way.

I created a page template named projects.php (Template Name: Projects) and added the script to list the projects in this page.

I added a page with the template selected as Projects.

However, when I'm viewing this page in the frontend, it calls the default archive page instead of the Projects page template.

How do I fix this?

The default archive page has its own format for displaying stuff, for example, the page title displays like Catagory: Projects.

I want a separate page template for the projects page and keep the archive page for the categories and tags. Just like for the blogs there's a blog page and then a separate archive page, I want something similar for the custom post type as well  instead of calling an archive page for everything!

Comment: Did you try naming your template `archive-projects.php` as per the codex? https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

Comment: Did you set `has_archive` when you registered your post type? WordPress automatically generates an archive if you want it, you don't need to create a page with a custom template and query.

Comment: @Samuel I didn't create a separate archive page for it. I just want that the custom post list should be called in the custom page template I created.

Comment: @Milo Yes I did set it to true

Comment: if you don't want to use it, you can set it to false and the conflict with your page will be gone. However, it's easier to deal with pagination and such if you just use the archive instead.

Comment: I tried setting it to false and still got the same result. Page called archive page instead of the page template I have created.

Answer (score 2):

Custom page templates are for pages - not post type archives :)

Naming your template file as `archive-projects.php` will cause Wordpress to select it for your Projects archive page.

You also don't need the `/* Template Name: Projects */` in there, as this template naming is default Wordpress behaviour. See the [visual overview of the template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview) to understand how you can name your template files so Wordpress will select them.

Alternatively, if you are wanting to *replace* the default Wordpress custom post type archive with your own page, just ensure your page has the same slug as the custom post type - in this case, that would be `projects`. You can change the slug of the page at the top of the post editor, just under the title.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely try it. But, if we don't have /* Template Name: Projects */, then how can we create a dynamic page for it from the WP backend UI?

Comment: If you want to use the template as a page template as well, then yes, you can include Template Name in there. However, usually you would create a separate template for your post type archive and for a page you wish to set a custom template for.

Comment: @TESTacy I just edited my answer to add another para at the end, which I think now might be what you're after.

Comment: So this will work only with the archive page? Wont a page template do the job instead?

Comment: Yes you can use a page template instead - but Wordpress will already do the querying work for you if you use an archive template :) Using a page template will probably only really be useful if you want to add custom content from the page itself as well.

Comment: Okay! So if I still want to use the page template and not the archive page, then how can I do that? Because I also tried adjusting the page slug as you mentioned but it didn't work. Still got the same result.

Comment: Although, I'd vote up your answer because it does work if you want to go the archive way! :)

Comment: Hmm.. try visiting the Settings -> Permalinks page after creating your page/updating the slug. Permalinks might need a refresh to take over the CPT archive. Thanks for the vote :)

Comment: How did you go with this in the end, @TESTacy?

Comment: For now I did it as per the archive way. Still am looking for a solution to get it directly in a page template!

Comment: @TESTacy Could you perhaps edit your question to add some details on _why_ you want to do this? It doesn't make a lot of sense, so perhaps we can suggest another solution for your problem.